# Unchecked Call to Data error, when adding data points to Series

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making an XY line chart, and am getting and Unchecked call warning when I add a data point

```
XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
series.setName("Temp Res graph");
for(int i = 1; i<800; i++) {
        XYChart.Data dp = new XChart.Data(i,Integer.parseInt(getTemp(i)));
        series.getData().add(dp);
        lineChart.getData().add(series);
}
```

Its a warning, but when I run the code I get a bunch of errors, that seem to be caused by those lines:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate series added
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unchecked warning is from your use of [raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/). Both `XYChart.Series` and `XYChart.Data` are generic types but you don't specify any generic parameters. Based on the values you're passing to the `Data` constructor you should be using `Number` for both parameters.

As for your error, you're adding `series` to your `lineChart` at the end of every iteration of your `for` loop. Move that code outside the loop (either before or after).

```
// Add generic parameters (uses the <> operator on the right)
XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
series.setName("Temp Res graph");
for(int i = 1; i<800; i++) {
    // Add generic parameters (uses the <> operator on the right)
    XYChart.Data<Number, Number> dp = new XChart.Data<>(i,Integer.parseInt(getTemp(i)));
    series.getData().add(dp);
}
lineChart.getData().add(series); // outside loop
```

Note that `LineChart` is also a generic type; don't forget to specify the generic parameters for it as well: `LineChart<Number, Number>`.